# вызов одного fxml с разными параметрами

Tags: java, javafx

имеется некий TabPane с несколькими табами естественно (все, за день, за неделю) внутри табов идентичная таблица по структуре но уже с разными данными.

не думаю что для каждого таба создать в scene builder'е свои таблицы, по этому решил создать отдельную сцену для таблицу и вызвать из основного контроллера
вроде как с помощью

```
<fx:include source="table.fxml" fx:id="table1"/>
```

можно получить таблицу, а вот не совсем понимаю как заполнять таблицу с нужными данными...

Comment: Могли бы вы более подробно описать ситуацию? У вас в итоге на каждую таблицу один fxml или на каждую таблицу своя пара fxml/controller?

fxml.loader() вызывает метод @FXML void initialize(), если это вам подойдет.

Comment: есть TabsController и для него tabsPage.fxml, есть контент в виде таблицы TableController и tablePage.fxml, для всех табов одинаковый по структуре таблица, т.к. одна таблица, надо передать этот полученный лист или каким то образом указать что при выборе/переходе табов сформировался/заполнялся таблица с соответствующими данными.

Comment: При инициализации табов, в них можно добавить tab.setUserData(Object) например с enum соответствующих вашим таблицам, сделать listener на select табы у tabPane, в котором вызывать у контроллера таблиц метод, заполняющий таблицы, передав ему содержимое энума tab.getUserData(), так он догадается какие данные загружать в таблицу. Это если нужно формировать таблицу каждый раз при выборе таба.

Comment: Спасибо @Maxim идея понятна... )